# HTML/PHP - Align text on character

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've got a webpage which prints strings from an SQLITE database. There are two values, questions and answers. What I'm trying to do is align the strings on the seperator '='.

What currently comes out:

```
a = b
hello = Hello.
bey = Bye.
```

What I want:

```
a     = b
hello = Hello.
bye   = Bye.
```

Is this possible within PHP/HTML? If so, how would I go on about doing that? Your answers are really appreciated!

Comment: Use an HTML table.

Comment: in html you'd have to split the lines up into three sections and align those. php could pad things out so there's extra spaces in the first chunk, but then you'd have to display that padded text in a `<pre>` block or using a mono-space font, and of course use `&nbsp;`, since repeated standard spaces will be collapsed down into a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>HTML Tables</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>a </td>
        <td>= </td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hello </td>
        <td>=</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bye </td>
        <td>=</td>
        <td>Bye.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/ismaakeel/9ujawg2u/4/

Answer (score 0):

Yes dear,

It is possible to

First you create table 3 * 3

and insert data into row

and hide table border,

then you get easily, what you want

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>a</td>
   <td>=</td>
   <td>b</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
   <td>hello</td>
   <td>=</td>
   <td>hello</td>
</tr>

 <tr>
   <td>bye</td>
   <td>=</td>
   <td>bye</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to print out plain, fixed-width text and not an HTML table, then you'd have to pull all the values from the database first and then loop through them a bit to figure out how many spaces to add before the `=` on each line.

First loop through each L-value identifier to get the longest length, and then do your output loop where you add in the right number of spaces (max length minus current length).